# Consulta union con Inner Join

Tags: oracle-sqldeveloper

Tengo la siguiente consulta en Oracle Developer que me esta tirando error:

```
SELECT * FROM
(
select distinct code, cbl, size, s1 seal, t2 term, plant, ta.cat2, ta.cat3, ta.descr from tblb
UNION
select distinct code, cbl, size, s2 seal, t2 term, plant, ta.cat2, ta.cat3, ta.descr from tblb
) tb
INNER JOIN 
(
SELECT  tbla.part_nbr comp, tbla.category_2_cd cat2, tbla.category_3_cd cat3, tbla.built_descr descr
FROM tbla
) ta
ON
ta.comp = tb.term
where tb = '0.55'
```

Me tira error en la línea del segundo `select ta.Descr`:

> *invalid identifier.*

¿A que se deberá ese error?

Comment: ta es otra tabla en otro select en otro from...

Answer (score 0):

Solucionado aqui la consulta:

```
SELECT * FROM
 (
select distinct code, cbl, size,s1 seal, t1 term, plant from tb
UNION
select distinct code, cbl, size,s1 seal, t1 term, plant from tb) tblb
INNER JOIN (SELECT cat2, cat3, Descr, plant, comp from ta) tbla
ON
tblb.term = tbla.comp
AND
tblb.plant = tbla.plant
where size = '0.55'
```

Se puede dar por solucionado.

Saludos

DS